# Windows 8.1 phone emulator in Windows 8.1 VM?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, hyper-v

I connect to a Windows 8.1 Pro VM through Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2008.

It looks like in order to run the Windows 8.1 phone emulator, you need to be running Windows 8.1 Pro that is capable on running Hyper-V.

Since I am already connecting to Windows through a VM, will I not be able to enable the necessary Hyper-V features to be able to start the Windows phone emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An often found solution is to run the VM inside VMWare. This allows you to enable Hyper-V inside the virtual machine. Here's a [detailed step-by-step guide](http://irisclasson.com/2014/05/04/video-installing-and-running-the-windows-phone-emulator-in-a-virtual-machine/).

As an alternative, it appears to be possible to enable Hyper-V inside the VM using the powershell command `Add-WindowsFeature -name RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools`, as found on [this blog](http://baudlabs.com/hyper-v-cannot-be-installed-a-hypervisor-is-already-running-error-when-trying-to-install-hyper-v-management-tools-in-virtualized-windows-server-2012/).

Both of these scenario's are unsupported, but appear to work fine.